# Non-ASCII output after restarting the Perl debugger

Tags: perl, debugging, unicode, utf-8

[**EDIT**: It turns out that the original version of this question contained two different issues masquerading as one.  (I realized this only after reading and working through tripleee's comment.)  Therefore, I split the original question into two.  I edited this post to include the issue I figured out thanks to tripleee's comment, and posted the second one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25871835/559827).  BTW, that second post incorporates the fix I came with to the problem described in this post, namely setting `STDOUT`'s encoding explicitly within the script, using `binmode`.]

---

I'll use the short demo script below to illustrate the problem.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
use strict;
use feature 'unicode_strings';
use POSIX 'locale_h';
use locale;
use utf8;

setlocale( LC_CTYPE, 'de_DE.UTF-8' );

my $non_ascii = 'ßäöüÄÖÜ';
print "$non_ascii\n";

my @non_ascii = split //, $non_ascii;
print "$_\n" for @non_ascii;

$DB::single = 1; 1;  # return control to DB
```

(The last line is effectively a breakpoint.)

OK, now I run this under the Perl debugger:

```
% perl -C -d dbtest.pl

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.37
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(dbtest.pl:8):            setlocale( LC_CTYPE, 'de_DE.UTF-8' );
  DB<1> c
ßäöüÄÖÜ
ß
ä
ö
ü
Ä
Ö
Ü
main::(dbtest.pl:17):           $DB::single = 1; 1;  # return control to DB
  DB<1>
```

So far so good: the script produced the expected output, and now the debugger has entered into single-step mode, and is waiting for input.

If I now just restart the debugger with `R`, and run the script again (with `c`, *exactly as before*), this is what happens:

```
  DB<1> R
Warning: some settings and command-line options may be lost!

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.37
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(dbtest.pl:8):            setlocale( LC_CTYPE, 'de_DE.UTF-8' );
  DB<1> c
\337\344\366\374\304\326\334
\337
\344
\366
\374
\304
\326
\334
main::(dbtest.pl:17):           $DB::single = 1; 1;  # return control to DB
  DB<1>
```

Furthermore, now `print` no longer produces human-readable output:

```
  DB<1> print $non_ascii
\337\344\366\374\304\326\334
```

How can keep the output looking human-readable after a restart?

Comment: "Warning: some settings and command-line options may be lost!" sounds like the explanation. In particular, is your `-C` getting misplaced?

Comment: @tripleee: thanks!  your comment led to a fix for the restart problem, but the problem with `x` remains.  It turns out my original question presented two different issues.  I couldn't figure out how to deal with this situation, so I just posted a new version of the question that isolates the problem with the `x`.  I'll have to revise the question in this thread so that it does not overlap with the new question...  Feel free to send in your comment as an answer for it.

Comment: Using `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';` instead of `-C` should address the issue.

Comment: Your own answer is better. Feel free to undelete and accept it.